# Trying to upcase single character (or region) selected *with multiple-cursors active*

Tags: multiple-cursors

I'm trying to get used to `multiple-cursors`. It's super useful but the way it interacts with many emacs builtin functions seems weird - perhaps I just don't quite understand how it works.

Eg. my current goal was editing a bunch of constants to add a `k` in front, easily done, but then the next character is currently lowercase and I want it to be upcase. upcase-word won't work because I want it to retain the camelcase chars in the word - so I can select a region with `C-[:space:] C-f` and now have a disjoint region covering all the characters to uppercase. But then `upcase-region` does nothing :(

Can someone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you running `upcase-region` using `M-x`? If not, try using `C-x C-u` instead. Multiple cursors doesn't seem to work well with manually invoked commands. For me it works using the shortcut.

Comment: As an alternative, perhaps you can just use a simple keyboard macro. Get to the next "constant" (however you define that), by searching or whatever, then insert `k` in front. (Repeat the macro with a large prefix arg.)

Answer (score 3):

You may have accidentally answered "no" to the question "Do upcase-region for all cursors? (y or n)" at some point in the past, which caused it to be added to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `mc/cmds-to-run-once` whereas you actually want it to be in <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `mc/cmds-to-run-for-all`.